# ARC Error while using RaptureXML

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I tried to use [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML) in my application as i came to know its easy to implement for parsing. Am trying to parse the remote XML file and get the images from it and view it as UIImageView. When i tried to call my remote XML file i got a warning and two errors as below,

- 'elementFromURL:' is deprecated
- "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RXMLElement", referenced from:objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
- clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The ViewController i used as show below,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myxml.com/Sample.xml"]];
    RXMLElement *rxmlProducts = [rootXML child:@"Products"]; 
    NSArray *myarray = [rxmlPlayers children:@"Main"];
    UIImage *currentImage = [myarray objectAtIndex:0];
    customimage.image = currentImage;
  }
```

My Remote XML file looks like this,

```
<Products>
  <Main id="1">
    <name>Main</name>
    <mainimage id="1">http://myimage.com/images/first.png</mainimage>
    <mainimage id="2">http://myimage.com/images/second.png</mainimage>
  </Main>
  <Category id="1">
    <name>category1</name>
    <categoryimage id="2">http://myimage.com/images/img1.png</categoryimage>
  </Category>
  <Category id="2">
    <name>category2</name>
    <categoryimage id="2">http://myimage.com/images/img2.png</categoryimage>
    <subcategoryimage id="1">http://myimage.com/images/img5.png</subcategoryimage>
    <subcategoryimage id="2">http://myimage.com/images/img4.png</subcategoryimage>
  </Category>
</Products>
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this error and how to parse the above Remote XML file using [RaptureXML.](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML)

Comment: Please include a link to the RaptureXML site.

Comment: @trojanfoe what would be the point?

Comment: @Till So I can look at the code/documentation.

Comment: @trojanfoe https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML

Comment: @Till Yeah cheers; it's something I think the OP should have considered and that's why I asked him to edit his question.

Comment: @trojanfoe Edited and added the link for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem of ARC error by this below way,as suggested by the [RaptureXML GitHub](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML/issues/29).

**For ARC problem**

Since this is a linker error

- Go to project settings, select your current build target, and hit the "Build Phases" tab. Under "Compile sources.
- Check whether `RXMLElement.m` is on that list, if not add the file in list. Now the ARC error will gets solved by linker.

**For 'elementFromURL:' is deprecated Problem**

- They don't recommend using elementURL: anymore. You can get away with it, but it leaves you unable to customize the network call as some people want (timeouts, etc.). They recommend using your favorite network library to get the XML data and then piping that into RaptureXML.

Answer (score 0):

OK there are 2 issues:

1) The author of RaptureXML has deprecated the `elementFromURL` method in this [commit](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML/commit/558ed59c74714a04904765f82c84bbb167e94ac5) with the following comment:

> It's recommended that you take care of the network operations yourself
>   and let RaptureXML take care of the XML

2) It looks like you aren't using a (static?) library that has been compiled with support for the iPhone Simulator (architecture i386).  To solve that you'll need to re-compile yourself, including the support or find one online that has this support already.

Comment: I can run my other apps working perfect. When i use RaptureXML am getting these errors. I had follwed the way of implementation as given in the https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML/blob/master/README.md